# Which one is older light or stars?

Tags: time, stars

I kind of feel that light is older than stars. But is there any scientific theory or hypothesis on it?

Comment: According to theory as I understand it stars took some time to form, while light is a form of energy which was in abundance. So, light came before stars, however you'll get a better answer in physics or astronomy SE.

Comment: What do you mean by 'older'?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape, I meant which came first.

Comment: Light emitted by stars can't be older than the stars itself. But the cosmic microwave background radiation was once light after the bing bang. This light may have existed before the first stars.

Comment: @Uwe is right. Certainly light existed first. As soon as there were particles with charge, their interaction started producing photons of a continuum of wavelengths. The CMB is (roughly speaking) the doppler-shifted echo of that.

Comment: @opu웃 this is an interesting question, and it might have an existing answer in either the [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) or the [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange sites already.